# Upload a file trough an API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I don't find how to do it in the Core version of ASP.NET.

I have found this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-image-to-server-using-web-api-2-0/

but every line is wrong in the Core version.

I got the current context:

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Request;
```

Comment: Did you try with `Request.Form.Files`

Comment: [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)

Answer (score 2):

You can send it via form-data from any client-side and take it in the action like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyAction([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{

}
```

you will be able to access it from the parameter or you can user

```
Request.Form.Files
```